# Azure Storage Account blob stream with Python

Tags: python, hdf5, azure-storage-account

Using the latest azure.storage.blob (12.4.0) python library, I need to open a stream on a blob without downloading it completely in memory.

I have hdf5 files stored in storage account, using h5py (2.10.0) I need to extract some information, read data without having the file loaded in memory. The files can contains many giga bytes of data.

```
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client('sample')
blob = container_client.get_blob_client('SampleHdF5.hdf5')

stream = BytesIO()
downloader = blob.download_blob()

# download the entire file in memory here
# file can be many giga bytes! Big problem
downloader.readinto(stream)

# works fine to open the stream and read data
f = h5py.File(stream, 'r')
```

Maybe there's another service more appropriate for this kind of need on Azure.

Comment: Did you mean get blob to stream? If so, this code will help: `with io.BytesIO() as input_io:
            blob_service.get_blob_to_stream(container_name=container_name, blob_name=blob.name, stream=input_io)`

Comment: the get_blob_to_stream seams to be available in an older version of azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice which is not available anymore. Maybe I miss something!

Answer (score 1):

`get_blob_to_stream` can be used with `azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice` refering to [here](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/ref/azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.html#azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice.BaseBlobService.get_blob_to_stream). There are packages that I used.

[image]

```
from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService
import io

connection_string = ""
container_name = ""
blob_name = ""

blob_service = BaseBlobService(connection_string=connection_string)
with io.BytesIO() as input_io:             
    blob_service.get_blob_to_stream(container_name=container_name, blob_name=blob_name, stream=input_io)
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: After trying on Windows and mac and making sure that it's the version 12.4.0 of azure-storage-blob package is installed, the azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice  is not found on both os with the latest version of python installed.

Comment: from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService is provided by azure-storage 0.30.0 which is not available anymore. The 12.4.0 package has many possibilities to open a stream to a file but in all the cases, they dowload the entire fiel in memory instead of just reading giving an open stream/

Comment: @FredericThibault azure-storage 0.37.0(the latest one but I install failed) is still available. I tried azure-storage 0.36.0, and it worked. It seems there is no better way than `get_blob_to_stream`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to make it works with the version 0.36.0. But unfortunately the get_blob_to_stream download the entire file in memory. I don't know if a service exists on Azure to work from an app service and open a file like if it s a local and only have a file stream to read, seek, ... without having all the file loaded in memory.

Comment: @FredericThibault What you want is download the blob to a local file? If so, `get_blob_to_path(container_name, blob_name, file_path)` is used to do.

Comment: I dont need to copy or download the entire file, I just need to open it. The file format is hdf5, it's like a database where we need to have an handle on the file and read what we need. I m taking a look at file share from Storage account and app service and it looks promising.

Comment: It seems not possible to get the stream of the blob, but don't store it in both memory and local.