# How to read pickle file from Azure Blob without downloading?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, pickle

So far, I am able to load it but I have to download it and it takes too much time. I want to read the pickle file directly.
Here's the code

```
def get_vector_blob(blob_name):
    connection_string = <connection string>
    container_name = <container name>
    blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, container_name, blob_name)
    downloader = blob_client.download_blob(0)
    
    # Load to pickle
    b = downloader.readall()
    vector = pickle.loads(b)
    
    return vector
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [readinto(stream)](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-storage-blob/12.3.2/azure.storage.blob.html#azure.storage.blob.StorageStreamDownloader.readinto) or `get_blob_to_stream`  from `azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice`

```
from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService
import io
connection_string = ""
container_name = ""
blob_name = ""
blob_service = BaseBlobService(connection_string=connection_string)
with io.BytesIO() as input_io:
blob_service.get_blob_to_stream(container_name=container_name, blob_name=blob_name, stream=input_io)
```

References: [Access azure blob storage files with python without downloading - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/628106/access-azure-blob-storage-files-with-python-withou.html) and [hdf5 - Azure Storage Account blob stream with Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507934/azure-storage-account-blob-stream-with-python)